# PHP CURL Background Process - REST API URL

Tags: php, rest, curl

I am trying to execute the background REST API Call with Curl 
library in php. I guess it is not working.

can you suggest me ?

```
$cum_url       = http://localhost/test/list;
$post = [ 'id' => $object->id ];
$ch = curl_init($cum_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**UPDATE:**  Cull error says "Timeout was reached".

Thanks,
Raja K

Comment: reference : http://www.paul-norman.co.uk/2009/06/asynchronous-curl-requests/

Comment: Please include your error or other findings in the question. How do you know it's not working? I hope you didn't really guess, but tested it first ;)

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I have added a db insert line in the REST URL. It's not pinging. It's not working after I have added curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1); for background process

Answer (score 0):

You need to transfer your post data from array to http parameter string, ex:

```
$cum_url = "http://localhost/test/list";
$post = [ 'id' => $object->id ];
$postdata = http_build_query($post);

$options = array (CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false, // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1",
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);
$ch = curl_init($cum_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, $options );
$res = null;
if(!curl_errno($ch)) {
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Of course, some option is optional depends on you, ex CURLOPT_USERAGENT. Just show you an example.

Comment: Thanks. Normal CURL is working. I am talking about background process. Are you saying that you're snippet support background process ?

Comment: Please refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php to make sure you understand the curl options and only use the neccessary options and not just copy options from other examples  ... Also CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER when set to true does not return web page, but returns the response as a string instead of outputting it directly ..

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand your question. If you are looking for send asynchronous call with curl, maybe you can try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26039848/php-asynchronous-curl-with-callback

Comment: DTH, thanks for your remind. Yes, you are right, always better to check the using options from document before using it.