# Force CURL request to not look for a response PHP

Tags: php, curl, node-red

EDIT: The proper thing to do is just to send a response from Node-red as hardillb pointed out below.

My CURL request is working fine and instantly, but I simply need to have the page visit the url and not wait around for a response.  I have tried every combination I can think of and my browser still sits waiting for a server response until timeout.

```
$url = 'http://example.com:1880/get?temperature='.$temperature;
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);


// 3. execute and fetch the resulting HTML output
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// 4. free up the curl handle
curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: Why not wait for a response? Have you forgotten to add a http-response node to your Node-RED flow?

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26039848/php-asynchronous-curl-with-callback

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024821/php-curl-required-only-to-send-and-not-wait-for-response

Comment: You are ABSOLUTELY right hardillb that it is easier to just have the response form node-red. I don't know why I never noticed that over there on the left side.

Comment: As far as the other posts...I appreciate the links.  I've just gotten mixed results from CURL when there was zero response.  Thanks for your time everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments.

The correct solution is to ensure your http-in node is paired with a http-response node in your Node-RED flow